# Python - Binary Search on Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, algorithm

Hi I have an inventory of items as such:

```
inventory = {1 : ["Lettuce", "Fresh Cut Lettuce", 1.30, 1000, False],
             2 : ["Apple", "Red big and round", 1.20, 1000, False],
             3 : ["Orange", "Orange big and round", 1.10, 1000, False],
             4 : ["Peach", "Pink big and round", 1.50, 1000, False],
             5 : ["Pear", "Green big and semi round", 1.30, 1000, False],
             6 : ["Plum", "Red small and round", 0.60, 1000, False]}
```

I wish to perform a Binary Search on this inventory by searching for the key `"Apple"`.

I understand that Binary Search only works on numbers is this true?

Because in Binary Search you compare to see if the key is `<` or `>` a mid point and I can't use those operators on strings.

If so is there another algorithm to search for an item in this inventory with the key `"Apple"`?

Comment: If you are to look up your inventory with `'Apple'`, you are having wrong keys in the first place. 1, 2, 3.. as keys if not serving any purpose should be replaced with first item in the list (if that does not duplicate).

Comment: Your keys are integers 1,2,3 etc. Not `'Apple'`

Comment: Binary search works on any data type that can be ordered.  However, your data has to already be sorted according to those values, so that you can tell which half must contain the desired value based on a comparison result.

Comment: Oh nono what i meant was that i want to search for an item in the dictionary using an element of the value. In my case its `'apple'`

Comment: @jasonharper Ohh okay thanks :) so in my case is there another algorithm I should look into to achieve what i'm trying to?

Comment: I recommend that you do your research on sorting and searching.  This is an old, large topic with **MANY** available references -- and is therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I gave you a duplicate link to solve your immediate problem.